# create array from string or variable

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to find the best way using PowerShell to create an array from the output of a variable.

I have the following code:

```
$ListNames = & "listNames.cmd" | Out-String
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
(c) 2016 - 2017 Use of this software is subject to license restrictions
::Microsoft Windows 7
::Microsoft Windows 7::name1
::Microsoft Windows 7::name2
::Microsoft Windows 7::name3
::Microsoft Windows 7::name4
::Microsoft Windows 7::name5
::Microsoft Windows 7::name6
::Microsoft Windows 7::name7
```

I **need** in an array everything from `name1` thru `name7`.

I attempted without success trying to convert it to a CSV using delimiter `:`, tried creating a `PSObject`, and a few other ways that didn't get me the result I was looking for.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$ListName -split '[\r\n]+' | Where{$_ -match '::.+?::(.+)'}|ForEach{$Matches[1]}`

Comment: Nice! Worked perfect.

Comment: All regex: `[regex]::Matches($ListNames, '(?m)(?<=::)([^:]+)$').value`

Comment: no regex if you hadn't used out-string but needs a split regex to undo what that did I think: `$ListNames -split "\`r?\`n" | Select-Object -Skip 2 | ForEach-Object { $_.replace('::Microsoft Windows 7::', '') }`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this:

1. Remove the `Out-String`. You want to process the output line-by-line anyway, so merging the lines would only require you to split them again later.
2. Limit the output to relevant lines by piping it through a `Where-Object` filter (`find` or `findstr` would probably work too).
3. Split each remaining line at `::` and pick the last field from each resulting array.

```bsh
& ".\listNames.cmd" | Where-Object {
    $_ -like '::*::*'
} | ForEach-Object {
    ($_ -split '::')[-1]
}
```

Another option would be a regular expression match as [@TheMadTechnician](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987988/powershell-create-array-from-string-or-variable#comment75005420_43987988) suggested:

```bsh
& ".\listNames.cmd" | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '^::.+?::(.+)'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $matches[1]
}
```